# Create a factory to build nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

The relation between those models is

- `airport HAS_MANY flights`
- `flight HAS_MANY flight_skus`

How could a create flight_sku with a parent and  a grand parent on a easy way with FactoryGirl

```
  before(:all) do
    @airports = AIRPORTS.collect{|airport| FG.create(:airport, code: airport)}
    @flight = FG.create(:flight, from_airport: @airports[0], to_airport: @airports[3])
    @sku = FG.create(:flight_sku, flight: @flight)
    @flight_2 = FG.create(:flight, from_airport: @airports[1], to_airport: @airports[2])
    @sku_2 = FG.create(:flight_sku, flight_id: @flight_2.id)
  end
```

## update: (not working version_

```
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `single_room=' for #<Room:0x007fcbed2e3d60>
   Did you mean?  singleton_method



factory :create_rooms_list do
    single_room
    twin_room
end

factory :single_room do
    name "單人房"
    guests 1
end

factory :twin_room do
    name "雙人房"
    guests 2
end
```

Comment: Please mark my answer as correct if it was any help 

Comment: What do you want to do with the :creat_rooms_list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
factory :flight_sku do
  other_fields
  flight
end

factory :flight do
  other_fields
  airport
end

factory :airport do
  other_fields
end
```

By calling `build(:flight_sku)`you would create a `flight`, with an `airport` and the a new `flight_sku` with said associations set.

By calling `create(:flight_sku)` you will create all of them.

By calling `build_stubbed(:flight_sku)` you will create stubbed resources of `flight_sku` and both associations.

Comment: your solution now works, when I call create `create_rooms_list`